# How to show colour change when customised radio button is selected?

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

I am new to coding generally, and have been working on a quiz program on HTML and CSS (data is from PostgreSQL, framework SpringBoot on Eclipse. PHP and JQuery not included in syllabus).

Here's my problem:

1. Now I have a list of answers where the user will have to select from.
2. Was hoping to have the colours of the button-like radio input? change colour when the user clicks on it.
3. Managed to create the buttons and the cursor when it hovers over the selections, but there's no change despite my CSS.

Can someone tell me where I did wrong? Big thanks in advance.

**※Updated HTML and CSS according to the advices in the comments + more code:**

This is the HTML code:

the screenshot of the id: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IeWK.png

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/result" data-th-object="${form}">
        <!-- ヘッダータイトル -->
        <div class="headerbackground">
            <h6>模擬試験オンライン</h6>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!-- 試験指示 -->
        <div class="examinstruction">
            <p>表示された言葉の英単語を以下から選び、</p>
            <p>OKボタンをクリックしてください。</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!-- question -->

        <div data-th-each="list, st : ${form.list}">
            <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">
                <span data-th-text="${list.questionCount}">n</span> <span>/</span> <span
                    data-th-text="${list.questionTotal}">/n</span>
            </p>
            <div class="questionborder">
                <p style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold"
                    data-th-text="${list.content}">question</p>
            </div>
            <!-- answer choice -->
            <fieldset style="border: 0">
                <div class="choiceradiobox"
                    data-th-each="choice, stat : ${list.choice}">
                    <input id="selectedchoice" data-th-name="|choice${st.count}|"
                        type="radio" data-th-value="${choice}"
                        />
                        <label
                        for="selectedchoice"><span data-th-text="${choice}"></span></label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <!-- 解答完了ボタン -->
        <div class="submitsection">
            <input class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-size: 25px"
                type="submit" onclick=validate() value="OK!">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio] {
     display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #455a64; 
    color: #eceff1; 
}

label {
    display: block; 
    margin: auto; 
    width: max-content; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top : 0.05em;
    padding-bottom: 0.05em;
    padding-left: 5em;
    padding-right: 5em;
    line-height: 45px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    border: solid #eceff1;
    background-color: #eceff1;
    padding-top: 0.05em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Added live test at the end**

**Unlike `class`, each `id` property must be unique in the whole document.**

[More about `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

**Matching `id` and `for` also need to be assigned for each pair of `input` and `label` to make the styles work.**

The `input[type="radio"]:checked + label` selector is not targeting the `label` properly.

This is because it uses adjacent sibling selector `+`, but `input` and `label` are not adjacent due to a `<br>` in between.

[More about CSS combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators)

To solve this, you could use a general sibling combinator `~` to target the `label`:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background: #455a64; 
    color: #eceff1; 
}
```

**OR** remove the `<br>` in between the `input` and `label`, and keep the original CSS:

```
<div class="choiceradiobox" data-th-each="choice, stat : ${list.choice}">
  <input
    id="selectedchoice"
    name="choice"
    type="radio"
    data-th-value="*{list[__${st.index}__].choice}"
  />
  <label for="selectedchoice"><span data-th-text="${choice}"></span></label>
</div>
```

Both ways should make `label` change color when `:checked`.

Hope this will help!

**LIVE TEST** (run with button below)

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  background: #455a64;
  color: #eceff1;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: max-content;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.05em;
  padding-bottom: 0.05em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid #eceff1;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  padding-top: 0.05em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="border: 0">
  <div class="choiceradiobox" data-th-each="choice, stat : ${list.choice}">
    <input
      id="selectedchoice1"
      name="choice"
      type="radio"
      data-th-value="*{list[__${st.index}__].choice}"
    /><br />
    <label for="selectedchoice1">selectedchoice1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="choiceradiobox" data-th-each="choice, stat : ${list.choice}">
    <input
      id="selectedchoice2"
      name="choice"
      type="radio"
      data-th-value="*{list[__${st.index}__].choice}"
    /><br />
    <label for="selectedchoice2">selectedchoice2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="choiceradiobox" data-th-each="choice, stat : ${list.choice}">
    <input
      id="selectedchoice3"
      name="choice"
      type="radio"
      data-th-value="*{list[__${st.index}__].choice}"
    /><br />
    <label for="selectedchoice3">selectedchoice3</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: After I changed the + to ~, at least one of the answers was selected when clicked. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @reinbowpuke too bad not all the components work, perhaps if more code could be posted we might be able to further advice. Anyways glad if it helps you at least get closer!

Comment: if it's not a bother for you, could you please review my code again? Only the first answer of the first question could be selected so I did some tweaking, but it somehow got stuck there. :(

Comment: I think if you a <p/> on the line before the </div>, you may get the desired effect of changing the color and background of the selected radio button. With getting styling correct when using Thymeleaf, I've resorted to playing with the HTML in a W3Schools "Try it" page. I'll post that in a followup answer.

Comment: @reinbowpuke and @pfurbacher I added a live test with the same code and it does seem to work. I think perhaps the `label` and `input` are not assigned the matching `id` and `for`, which caused it to fail, since in posted HTML in question they seem to be only hard coded.

Comment: thank you @JohnLi and @pfurbacher! It seemed to work on W3Schools "Try it" page and other online reviewers, but just not when it's accessed from localhost:8080 and I just can't understand why. :/ (I've added more code too...!)

Comment: @reinbowpuke Any chance it can be checked if each group of `input` and `label` on your side had a matching and unique `id` and `for`?

Comment: @JohnLi I checked the id and for, they were matching (will include a screenshot as well)

Comment: @reinbowpuke It didn't work because all `input` had same `id`. Each one of the `input` need to have an unique `id`, and the `label` of the same pair need a matching `for`.  In this case, I think both can be set as something like `stat.index`, so each pair will be different. Not sure if this is the only issue, but hope it would help.

Comment: @JohnLi the problem really was with the id and index! It worked perfectly now, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code into this [W3Schools "Try it"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio) runner page.
Delete all the code that appears on the left hand side first, then paste.
I double the input element so that the effect can be seen in this code. Once you are satisfied with the styling, just delete the extra dummy radio button. You will notice that I included @John Li's CSS, and changed you `width: max-content;` to `width: auto;` (just playing around).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<style>
input[type=radio] {
     display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background: #455a64; 
    color: #eceff1; 
}
label {
    display: block; 
    margin: auto; 
    width: auto; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top : 0.05em;
    padding-bottom: 0.05em;
    padding-left: 5em;
    padding-right: 5em;
    line-height: 45px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    border: solid #eceff1; 
    background-color: #eceff1;
    padding-top: 0.05em;
}
</style>
</header>
<body>

<h1>Display Radio Buttons</h1>

<form action="">
  <div>
   <input
    id="selectedchoice1"
    name="choice"
    type="radio"
    data-th-value="*{list[__${st.index}__].choice}"
  />
  <label for="selectedchoice1"><span data-th-text="${choice}">meow</span></label> 
  <p/> <!-- this seems to prevent bleeding of the color from top down. 
Neither br or div work. -->
  <input
    id="selectedchoice2"
    name="choice"
    type="radio"
    data-th-value="*{list[__${st.index}__].choice}"
  />
 <label for="selectedchoice2"><span>bark</span></label>
 </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But it seems to work perfectly on the online snippet sites I tried, and when I added the tiny <p /> on my IDE no selection could be made at all...